# How do I know if my Australian ETA was approved?

Tags: visas, australia, application-status, eta

I would like to know is my visa application being approved or not

I receive an email saying I need to check on eta.immi.gov.au after 12 hours
but after I check in I just received this only :

> Reference number
>   expire date 5 April 2017
>   period stay 3 months
>   entries multiple visa
>   condition NO WORK- business visitor activity only

that's all so how do I know if this application is approved or not?

Can someone assist me?

Comment: ? What's not clear. Yes, it's approved, you can enter multiple times until 5 april 2017, stay at most three months and can't work.

Comment: Why would it have an expiration date if it wasn't approved?

Answer (score 11):

Yes your ETA was approved. You received an email stating the expiry date of the ETA, the maximum duration of your stay, the number of entries and the conditions attached to the visa. According to the website of the Australian Department of Immigration and Border Protection, [these are the details you'll find in a visa approval email](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/how-will-i-know-if-my-visa-application-has-been-approved):

> #### How will I know if my visa application has been approved?
>
> We will tell you.
>
> If the visa is granted, we will let you know:
>
> - when you can use the visa
> - the visa grant number
> - any conditions attached to the visa.​
>
> If the visa is not granted, we will send you a letter or email advising:
>
> - why the visa was refused
> - your review rights (if any)
> - the time limit for lodging an appeal (if applicable).

If you are still unsure about whether or not your ETA was approved, you can use [the appropriate official online service](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas?submit=check) to check its status.

Answer (score -2):

What you received is just an expiry date of your ETA. You will know when they call you or email you.

Comment: How would the OP not be approved if he has an expiry date? If you have an expiry date and conditions, obviously you've been approved.